# Is there a way to programmatically define the position of MToolbarElements in an MToolBar?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am developing an Eclipse rcp application to which various plugins are contributed. Each plugin has its own processor, which programmatically inserts further elements into possibly existing MToolBars (with existing MToolBarElements). The order of the inserted elements depends on the initialization order of the plugins, which is not deterministic except for dependencies between the plugins. But creating an artificial dependency between the plugins to force the initialization order of the plugins is not an alternative.

Is there an out of the box way to arrange the elements relative to each other? For example, element X must always be inserted into the toolbar after element Y with the id "foo.bar". 
Or do I have to manage the order in which the elements are added to the toolbar myself?

Each of the plugins defines its own processor

```
public class ApplicationModelProcessor {
  @Execute 
  public void execute(
    final MApplication application, 
    final ToolBarBuilder toolbarBuilder) {
  // ToolBarBuilder is a class providing methods to configure toolbar
  // elements and appending them to existing toolbars. So after the
  // configuration of the builder "build" is called and toolbar elements
  // are added to (existing) toolbars according to the configuration of
  // the builder
  toolbarBuilder.doSomeConfiguration();
  toolbarBuilder.build();
}
```

In the ToolBarBuilder class a method updateToolItem exists which effectively adds the MToolBarElement to a MToolBar

```
public class TooBarBuilder {
  public MToolBarElement build() {
    // The code happening here basically searches for existing MToolBar or 
    // creates a new MToolBar according to a given configuration of the 
    // builder
    MToolBar toolbar = findOrCreateToolBar();

    // and adds a new MToolBarElement to the given MToolBar
    return updateToolItem(toolbar);
  }


  // This method is invoked at some point during the execution of the provided processor. The toolBar is looked up before and provided to the method-
  private MToolBarElement updateToolItem(final MToolBar toolBar) {
    final MToolBarElement result = createHandleToolItem();

    // At this point I could manage the order by myself but is there a better way to do this?
    toolBar.getChildren().add(result);

    return result;
  }
}
```

Some plugins provide MToolBarElements to the same MToolBar though their own ApplicationModelProcessor registered at the "org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model" extension point.

**GIVEN** a plugin providing toolbar items 1 and 2

**AND** another plugin providing toolbar item 3

**WHEN** starting the application

**THEN** the order of the toolbar items must be constant (the absolute order of items is not so important, but the order should always remain the same)

Currently sometimes it is 1,2,3 or 3,2,1

Comment: Maybe use placeholder Separators and add the items after the appropriate separator.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to change the implementation from directly adding MToolBarElements to the MToolBar to adding MToolBarContributions and let take Eclipse care of adding the MToolBarElements refenrenced by the MToolBarContripution to the correct position in the MToolBar:

```
@Creatable
public class TooBarBuilder {

  @Inject
  private MApplication application;

  private String positionInParent;

  // The positionInParent is an expression that represents a position
  // relative to another element in the MToolBar, for example:
  // "after=another.toolbar.item.id"
  public ToolBarBuilder positionInParent(final String positionInParent) {
    this.positionInParent = positionInParent;
    return this;
  }

  public MToolBarElement build() {
    // The code happening here basically searches for existing MToolBar or 
    // creates a new MToolBar according to a given configuration of the 
    // builder
    MToolBar toolbar = findOrCreateToolBar();

    // and adds a new MToolBarElement to the given MToolBar
    return updateToolItem(toolbar);
  }


  // This method is invoked at some point during the execution of the provided processor. 
  // The toolBar is looked up before and provided to the method.
  private MToolBarElement updateToolItem(final MToolBar toolBar) {
    final MToolBarElement result = createHandleToolItem();
    MToolBarContribution contribution = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createToolBarContribution();
    contribution.setElementId(getContributionId()); // any elementId is ok, details how the id is created are not of interest for the solution
    contribution.setParentId(toolbar.getElementId());
    contribution.setPositionInParent(positionInParent);

    // after all model processors have been executed the MToolBarContribtions 
    // are evaluated. MToolBarElements in the created MToolBarContributions 
    // are added to the MToolBars referenced by the parentId. During this process 
    // the MToolBarElements are positioned relatively to each other according to
    // "positionInParent"
    application.getToolBarContributions().add(contribution);
  }
}
```